# QtС++. Доработать поиск файлов в директории и поддиректориях

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, qt5, поиск

Есть код:

```
 // Получение списка файлов в папке
    QStringList nameFilter;
        QDir dir(MTEPathTMP);
        nameFilter.clear();
        nameFilter << "*.png";

        QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList( nameFilter, QDir::Files );
        QFileInfo fileinfo;

        nameFilter.clear();
        foreach (fileinfo, list) nameFilter << fileinfo.absoluteFilePath();
```

Он ищет файлы по маске в директории.

НО! Он не умеет смотреть в поддиректории. Как можно его доработать, чтоб он мог искать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уже обсуждалось [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052460/recursively-iterate-over-all-the-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in). Я бы рекомендовал не изобретать велосипед с рекурсивной функцией, а применить готовый класс [QDirIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#details) со специальным флагом в параметрах.

```
QDirIterator it("/sys", QStringList() << "scaling_cur_freq", QDir::NoFilter, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    QFile f(it.next());
    f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    qDebug() << f.fileName() << f.readAll().trimmed().toDouble() / 1000 << "MHz";
}
```